# Kendo-UI Excel export with header and footer content

Tags: excel, user-interface, kendo-ui, header, export

I have a requirement with a project for the export of excel documents to contain an excel header and footer.
The header is required to have text and the company logo while the footer needs pagination.
Is this currently possible with the UI framework? 
I know we have access to modify/add cells but this wont suffice.

Another option would be to export the data and allow a back end module to process the information but when i do this i lose all the grouping information as all i currently export is the columns and raw data using `grid.dataSource.data().toJSON()`. Is there a way to export and keep the structure as seen on screen ?

Comment: I recent did an implementation in which I created an excel on the fly when the user hits the generate report button. Maybe you can try to create an workbook object and configure it with a header and  a footer and then dump your data in the worksheet. 
http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ooxml/workbook

Comment: So its possible to use a pre-existing excel document as a template? Then in excelExport i chose the document and tell it to write it to that ?

Comment: If template is what you are looking forward to, then design wise:
1.  I can think you create 1 or more kendo worksheet classes in javascript
2. Load them based on the user template selection and push the json data in them
3. Then generate the excel on the fly using 
       `kendo.saveAs({
              dataURI: workbookData,
              fileName: "<file name>.xlsx"
       });`

Comment: If i create a worksheet in JS am i able to add a header (including image) and footer before populating with the workbookData ?

Comment: I am not sure of how to add image. 

For Header, Data and Footer please check this url http://dojo.telerik.com/eviDIw

I just created that sample on telerik site. Hope that help!

Comment: Thansk for all your help but this isnt exactly what i need. I need the ability to add stuff to the header of an excel document so it spans across multiple pages .. For example if you were using excel you could go to this option and set it. - eg https://www.google.com.au/search?q=add+header+excel&espv=2&biw=1920&bih=908&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj-iOrz3NTQAhUMMo8KHQIRBLsQ_AUIBygC#imgrc=qATn5wWrjqnF4M%3A

Comment: You are welcome @ryan :). Sheet in Telerik Workbook is an Array, so you can add one or more worksheets with header and footer. I think, you should reach out to Telerik support to get an answer for the image part. All the best.